# Disabling OSX menu bar in VirtualBox fullscreen

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox

I am trying to run Linux Mint/ubuntu using VirtualBox on OSX. My problem is that the OSX menubar keeps appearing when mouse gets on top of screen in fullscreen mode. I would like to stop this effect. There are a number of results on google although most are outdated. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking to only disable it when in full screen mode?

Comment: preferably yes. Or at least in the screen the VM is running even if its not fullscreen.

Comment: This question has been around forever, but could really use an answer (one that's works with the latest Mac OS version).  I already tried adding a bounty once, and it expired, but if anyone adds a correct answer I promise to reward it with a new bounty.

Comment: It's been a long time indeed

Comment: I can only assume it is not possible, or too much hassle to make it worth

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution [described here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21676#p305585), although it's a bit of a hack, and involves modifying the VirtualBox plist file. I can confirm it works on VirtualBox 6.0.6 with macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

> Go to Applications Folder.
>
> Right click on VirtualBox.app > Show Package Contents. Go to
>   Contents/Resources; right click on VirtualBoxVM.app > Show Package
>   Contents.
>
> You won't have write permissions for the `Info.plist` file, so an easy
>   option is to copy it the desktop; make the required additions; then
>   move it back and overwrite the original file (admin password
>   required). Copy this file (not the VirtualBox.app one!):
>   `Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/Info.plist`
>
> Add this line to the copied `Info.plist` file using a good text editor
>   (I use gedit):
>   `<key>LSUIElement</key> <string>1</string>`
>   The command needs to be inserted at the correct
>   place, i.e. between "LSCanProvideIMVideoDataSource" and
>   "NSHighResolutionCapable"; or else it will not work.
>
> Make sure VirtualBox is not running and move the `Info.plist` file back
>   to the original location; overwriting the one inside
>   `VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents` (admin password required).
>
> OS X Mavericks actually keeps plist data in RAM, so logging out,
>   restarting, or resetting the parameter RAM may be also be required
>   before the `Info.plist` file changes will take effect. Then launch
>   VirtualBox.app, and start up your virtual machine. The VirtualBox.app
>   menu should still be there, but the VirtualBoxVM.app instance will
>   lose its menu bar and application switcher icon.